# Button is not triggered in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in react, and i'm can't understand why simple button is not working.

```
export default class PlayerList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      players: [],
      convocPlayers: []
    }
    this.sendConvoc = this.sendConvoc.bind(this)
  }

  async sendConvoc() {
    try {
      let data = this.state.convocPlayers;
      await axios.post('/players/convoc', {
        players: data
      });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <PlayerForm addPlayer={(user) => this.addPlayer(user)}></PlayerForm>
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between mt-8">
          <span className="text-3xl">Liste des joueurs</span>
          <PrimaryButton onClick={() => this.sendConvoc}>Envoyer la convocation</PrimaryButton>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

My PrimaryButton component :

```
export default class PrimaryButton extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <button type={this.props.type} onClick={() => this.onClick} className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    )
  }
  
  onClick() {
    var clickFunction = this.props.onClick || null;
    if (clickFunction) {
      clickFunction()
    }
  }
}
```

The sendConvoc function is never triggered when I click on the "PrimaryButton", if anyone has a solution, thank you in advance

Comment: `onClick={() => this.sendConvoc}` ---> `onClick={() => this.sendConvoc()}` OR `onClick={this.sendConvoc}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the onClick function to either `onClick={() => this.onClick()}` or just `onClick={this.onClick}`

Answer (score 1):

We must understand why your function is not triggered. When we specify an event ie `onClick`, React expects us to pass a function not call the function.

✅ Correct - Passing a function

```js
 <PrimaryButton onClick={this.sendConvoc}>

 // passing an inline function
 <PrimaryButton onClick={() => this.sendConvoc()}>
 <PrimaryButton onClick={() => alert('hello')}>
```

For inline function, notice that we need to call the function inside, otherwise the inline function will return the function definition (not calling the function).

❌ Incorrect - calling a function

```js
 <PrimaryButton onClick={this.sendConvoc()}>
 <PrimaryButton onClick={alert('hello')}>
```

For your case, the solution in `PrimaryButton` component is to call the function inside the inline function. Also, we probably don't need an inline function there which is a simpler solution.

```js
// BEFORE
// the issue here is we forgot to call `this.onClick`, we return function definition of `this.onClick` here. 
<button type={this.props.type} onClick={() => this.onClick}

// AFTER
<button type={this.props.type} onClick={() => this.onClick()}

// or
<button type={this.props.type} onClick={this.onClick} // simpler
```

In `PlayerList` component

```
// BEFORE
<PrimaryButton onClick={() => this.sendConvoc}>

// AFTER
<PrimaryButton onClick={() => this.sendConvoc()}>

// or
<PrimaryButton onClick={this.sendConvoc}>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain, I understand now!